# Simplified path during coding

Tags: c#, path

How can I simplify the path to `C:\Users\Administrator\\Desktop\\asd.txt` because I want to make the location string to be inputted through text box. here is the code that I have made. I want to make it easier for other people to search the path.

Here is the error.

> first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\khairishafiq\Desktop\hash application v1.5\hashapplication\bin\Debug\using System.Collections.Generic;'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Code:

```
    string location = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\asd.txt";
    int i = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void cuba()
    {
        var desiredText = File.ReadLines(location).ElementAt(i);
        string s = desiredText.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = s;
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
        textBox1.Text= mc[0].Groups[1].Value;
        textBox2.Text= mc[1].Groups[1].Value;
        textBox3.Text = mc[2].Groups[1].Value;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cuba();
    }
```

Comment: why not have a button/menu item that opens a `FileOpenDialog`?, you can always provide a default directory for this to open on

Comment: You're not on the administrator account. Do you have access rights?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean: getting the location of the desktop, you can use this code:

```
string desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

Then `location` is, when the file name `asd.txt` is fixed:

```
string location = Path.Combine(desktopFolder, @"asd.txt");
```

If not, you should use something to let the user choose the file itself, for example the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string location = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

Comment: actually, that is an example. the application that I'm making allow user to insert the path manually(from anywhere in the pc) but when inserted the normal path, an error occur. it need the double back slash to recognize the path.

Comment: So what is the problem then? Your question is unclear. Is your problem the regex?